# DGS Code Generation plugin: generateJava not working

Tags: build.gradle, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I am trying generate pojo files from schema using this guide https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/

*build.gradle.kts*

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation(project(":graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter"))
    implementation(project(":graphql-dgs-subscriptions-websockets-autoconfigure"))
    implementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.0")

    api("com.graphql-java:graphql-java:${Versions.GRAPHQL_JAVA}") //v 16.2
}

// Using plugins DSL
plugins {
    id("com.netflix.dgs.codegen") version "4.4.1"
}

tasks {
    generateJava {
//        schemaPaths = ["${projectDir}/src/main/resources/schema"] // List of directories containing schema files
        packageName ="com.example.packagename" // The package name to use to generate sources
        generateClient = true // Enable generating the type safe query API
    }
}
```

Getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)
    at graphql.parser.antlr.GraphqlLexer.<clinit>(GraphqlLexer.java:337)
    ... 231 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
    ... 233 more
```

I tried older versions of plugin, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a classpath conflict with ANTLR. This is very likely caused by another Gradle plugin that pulls in another (probably older) version of ANTLR.
The easy workaround is to re-order your plugins, putting the codegen plugin before the other plugin. Hopefully, the other plugin works with the newer version of ANTLR, but usually, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in other project that use gradle, and it works.